# How to resolve IndexError while doing Monte Carlo for 1000 runs?

Tags: machine-learning, python, pandas, jupyter, monte-carlo

Below code runs without any problem, however when I run the same code using Monte Carlo Analysis for 1000 runs, it gives IndexError. Can someone explain why this happens. Thanks

```
X = df1.drop("Gender", axis = 1)
y = df1.Gender
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2)
nb = CategoricalNB()
nb.fit(X_train,y_train)
nb_pred = nb.predict(X_test)
nb_accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test,nb_pred)
nb_accuracy
```

> output: 0.6279486413854882

```
X = df1.drop("Gender", axis = 1)
y = df1.Gender
for i in range(1000):
    X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2, random_state = i)
    #CategoricalNB Naive Bayes Model
    nb = CategoricalNB()
    nb.fit(X_train,y_train)
    nb_pred = nb.predict(X_test)
    nb_accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test,nb_pred)
print("CategoricalNB Naive Bayes Accuracy:{}".format(nb_accuracy))
```

> IndexError: index 74 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 74